# Trying to generate random array of integers, getting the same list each run. C++

Tags: c++, random, negative-number

Why does this result in the same array every time i run it?

```
int arr[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 11 + (-5); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::srand(std::time(0));` to set the random seed. For reproducible results, use the same seed, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand.

Comment: Using `srand` for random numbers has not been the best standard-based solution for several years.

Comment: Ok, that's news for me - what is a better solution?

Comment: @DavidStutz See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Ah ok, for C++11 - thanks for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to *seed* the random number generator, for example with the current time.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: Using `srand` for random numbers has not been the best standard-based solution for several years.